# How to get correct exitcode in when running python script from another Script?

Tags: python, exit-code

I have a file one.py

```
import sys
sys.exit(-23)
```

when I'm calling it from another file using both

```
ans = subprocess.call("python c:\python27\one.py")
                  or 
ans = os.system("python c:\python27\one.py")
```

it returns me value "2" and I want value as -23.

How do we do it ?

**EDIT**: Somebody marked this as possible duplicate of Another question .. which is a bash script but actually this question is related to python and it's calls where how exitcodes work.. how to run another python script has many answers but no one has discussed exit codes in that one .. infact i searched properly that one before asking question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my bash function return the wrong value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394930/why-does-my-bash-function-return-the-wrong-value)

Comment: @tripleee read the question ... it is about python ...

Comment: No, it is about what exit codes the underlying platform supports.

Comment: Okay may be.. but the thing is it is related to python programs.. You have way more reputation than mine.. so you may be knowing more than me. but that question did not answer my question with all due respect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 problems

1) you use negative exit codes, and they are not always possible. you might get 233 as exit code (the exit code is treated as a unsigned byte so it can be between 0 - 255)

2) you get an error when you run this because you try to run it in a shell form , you can make this work with

```
ans = subprocess.call(['python',r"c:\python27\one.py"]) # This r before addr. is important.. else you will still get the same value
```

or the less recommended way shell=True argument like this

```
ans = subprocess.call(r"python c:\python27\one.py", shell=True)
```

but that is not recommended because of security issues (if the user input can affect your command)

Comment: The value  I put up in sys.exit(12) like this but still answer is 2 only

Comment: perhaps you need to put r"c:\python27\one.py" ( add a r at the beginning) as the string contains \. if this doesnt help, then check what happens when you run it from cmd like "python c:\pyhon27\one.py"